# How to call the setListAdapter in android

Tags: android, listview

I have a class not extend from ListActivity, so how can I replace this code without error?

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
  this,
  R.layout.sbooks_row,
  cursor, from,
  to
);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
ListView myList=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

myList.setAdapter(adapter);
```